# Как проверить совпадение строки в списке?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть строка

```
"Привет Андрей"
```

Есть Список

```
"Привет"
"Пока"
"Погода"
```

Как мне проверить есть ли совпадение строки со значением в списке через `linq`?
Пробую вот так, но пишет `false`

```
var z = names.Any(x => x.Contains("Привет Андрей"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесу свои 5 копеек с использованием регулярок:

```
var list = new List<string>(){
    "Привет","Пока","Погода"
};
var str="Привет Андрей";
var result=list.SelectMany(x => Regex.Matches(str, $@"\b{Regex.Escape(x)}\b").Cast<Match>().Select(m =>m.Value)).Any();
```

В простых случаях- это большой оверхед по сравнению со строковыми функциями, но если что-то экзотическое нужно искать, то может помочь.

Comment: Меня пугает, что ТС выбрал Ваш ответ хД Спасибо, что указали, что это больше про разнообразие вариантов, нежели реальное решение поставленное задачи, а то будущие поколения могут пойти по "кривой дорожке" :D

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я не удивлюсь если минус моему ответу влепил автор вопроса :D

Comment: @Andrew: возможно, хотя среди ответов - Ваш наиболее правильный)

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "Привет Андрей";
string[] keywords = { "Привет", "Пока", "Погода" };

var result = keywords.Any(keyword => input.Contains(keyword));
```

Comment: Если заменить `Привет Андрей` на `Приветище Андрей` то возвратит `true` хотя в keywords нету слова "Приветище"

Comment: Это не значит, что нужно минусовать ответ :) Вы не дали точных условий - я не дал тот ответ который вы ждали.

Comment: Вопрос задавал не я :) Но по вопросу, мне кажется, понятно что нужно точное вхождение слова) Если бы требовалось неточное вхождение - это было бы оговорено. А не наоборот.

Comment: Нет, как раз кажется что наоборот :(

Comment: Ваш вариант всё равно лучше

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] keywords = { "Привет", "Пока", "Погода" };

var rez1 = "Привет Андрей".Split().Intersect(keywords).Any();
// rez1 == true

var rez2 = "Приветище Андрей".Split().Intersect(keywords).Any();
// rez2 == false
```